# $\int \sqrt{4-\tan^2x} \sec^2x \, dx $ via substitution method

Tags: integration

I am trying to determine via substitution method

$$\int \sqrt{4-\tan^2x} \sec^2x \, dx$$
$$t = \tan x $$
$$dt=\sec^2x\,dx$$
$$\int \sqrt{4- t^2} \, dt$$
$$t=2\cos\theta$$
$$dt=- 2\sin\theta \, d\theta$$
$$\int 2\sin\theta (- 2\sin\theta \, d\theta)  $$
$$\int 2(-2\sin^2\theta) \, d\theta  $$
$$\int 2( \cos2\theta -1 ) \, d\theta  $$

Is there any better substitution and how to think about that ?

Comment: Try $tanx=2sint$ as a possibility. You get "it" done in one go....but yours look fine. But a nice continuation is, how are you going to do your back substitution? This isn't just integration here....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in previous comment and answer, let $$\tan(x)=2\sin(t)\implies x=\tan ^{-1}(2 \sin (t))\implies dx=\frac{2 \cos (t)}{4 \sin ^2(t)+1}$$ All of the above makes $$I=\int \sqrt{4-\tan^2(x)} \sec^2(x) \, dx=\int 2 \sqrt{4-4 \sin ^2(t)} \cos (t)\,dt=4\int\cos^2(t)\,dt$$ Now, using $\cos^2(t)=\frac 12 (\cos(2t)+1)$, $$I=2 t+\sin (2 t)$$